# Why doesn't VS Code TypeScript IntelliSense suggest interfaces from nested namespaces for implementing?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, nested, namespaces, intellisense

I have a two-level nested namespaces with bunch of interfaces in global scope.

```
declare global {
  namespace A {
    namespace B {
      interface I1 {
      }
      interface I2 {
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I write, for example, some class C with `A.B.I1` interface implementation.

```
class C implements A.B.I1 {}
```

TS compiler implements it properly, but when typing `A.B ...` there is no suggestions of interfaces, declared in namespace `B`.

I checked in other IDEs: suggestions appear in WebStorm and not in Visual Studio 2019.

VS Code 1.43

TS 3.8.0

I didn't find anything with such issue.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. When extending other classes this is not a problem just with extending or implementing interfaces from nested namespaces. Is there any further information on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour got added in TypeScript v4.1 (I don't know exactly which commit / issue ticket though).

- [4.0 Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.5#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAOwIYFtgGcxIMbDgQTgG8AoOc0SWRVDLXOAIWLPLcungEsEZgoAZjjwBJAIws2bAL6spHajz6DhcEQCZJUuLJklZJbABsk6dHADCcLijBHgaXufwA6Ri4D0AKjgAeALRwYFAY5tgwUEYA1JiqXh7E0kA)
- [4.1 Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.5#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAOwIYFtgGcxIMbDgQTgG8AoOc0SWRVDLXOAIWLPLcungEsEZgoAZjjwBJAIws2bAL6spHajz6DhcEQCZJUuLJklZJbABsk6dHADCcLijBHgaXufwA6Ri4D0AKjgAeALRwYFAY5tgwUEYA1JiqXh7E0kA)
- [Release Notes link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html)
- [GitHub Release link](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/releases/tag/v4.1.2)